# ¿Cómo sustituir el uso de return dentro de un método?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He estado haciendo este codigo del juego "Toque y fama", todo iba bien con la programacion hasta que mi profesor dijo y cito textual.

> Solo pueden usar `int, float, bool, complex, comparadores,(>,>=,<,<=,==,!=,in,not in), and, or, not,if/elif/else, while, + str`
> y el modulo `random`, funciones cque entreguen como resultado o pidan parametros (random, randint,choice)

Despues le pregunte si se podia usar return y me dijo que no

```
    import random
    # Funcion para generar numero aleatorio
    def rand_num(x):
      a=''
      while x>0:
        z=str(random.randint(1,9))
        while z in a:
          z=str(random.randint(1,9))
        a+=z
        x-=1
      return >>>**a este return de aqui lo tengo que cambiar, porque no lo puedo usar y no se como hacerlo para mi codigo**
    # Cuantos toque y famas tiene el intento
    def acierto(x,y,z):
      i=0
      j=0
      toque=0
      fama=0
      if i+1<=y:
          while j<y:
            if x[j] in z:
              toque+=1
              if x[j] == z[j]:
                fama+=1
            j+=1
          return('Toques:',toque,'- Famas:',fama) >>>**Lo mismo aca, alguna idea de como puedo reemplazarlo sin necesidad de hacer de nuevo el codigo?**
    
    p=0
    g=0
    jg=0
    jj=1
    #variable jj para repetir el juego cuantas veces sea necesario
    #se acumulan con jg
    while jj==1:
      jg+=1
      n=int(input('Escoja el largo del número: '))
      while n<4 or n>9:
        n=int(input('Intente de nuevo. Escoja el largo del número: '))
      nn=rand_num(n)
      #para mostrar el numero
      #print(nn)
      i=0
      gg=0
      #gg nos dira cuando gane
      while i<n and gg==0:
        i+=1
        #si famas = a la cantidad de numeros(n),gana. Se acumulan en g
        t=input(f'Intento {i}: ')
        while len(t)!=n and i<n:
          i+=1
          t=input(f'Intente de nuevo. Intento {i}: ')
        if len(t)==n:
          aa=acierto(t,n,nn)
          print(aa)
          #Si famas es igual a la cantidad de números (n), gana. Se acumulan en la variable g
          if int(aa[-1])==n:
            print('¡Felicitaciones! Has acertado en',i,'intentos.')
            gg=1
            g+=1
      #Si gg esta intacta, el usuario pierde. Se acumulan en la variable p
      if gg==0:
        print('Fin del Juego. La secuencia era',nn)
        p+=1
      jj=int(input('¿Desea Jugar de nuevo? 1=Sí / 0=No: '))
    print('Partidas jugadas:',jg,'- Ganadas:',g,'- Perdidas:',p)
    print('Tu WinRate es del ' + str(g*100//jg) + '%')
```

Comment: Si no puedes usar un *return* entonces analiza que naturaleza deben tener tus métodos ¿son para establecer el valor de una propiedad o para retornar un cálculo?

Comment: Retornar un calculo

Comment: Python27 o Python 3.7? Algo va de uno al otro

Comment: python 3.7 estoy

Comment: Puedes usar una variable global, pero si eso es lo que tu profesor pretende, yo le daría una nota de `F-` al profesor. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es muy limpio, pero puedes usar diccionarios, si defines un diccionario fuera del scope de las funciones luego puedes modificarlo dentro de estas y usarlo a lo largo de la aplicación
otra opción es usar global

de todos modos me parece que lo que tu profesor quiere es que replantees el código para hacer innecesario el return

Comment: En ese caso podría usar cualquier variable global ...